# How do I prevent auto-scrolling to the top in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works in all other browsers and I have no idea what the problem is. I'm kind of in a hurry so I thought I'd ask you guys in case I missed anything obvious. I have a link you click on which initiate a popup, and in Firefox (and possibly opera) the page auto scrolls back to the top.

```
    $('[class*=popup-link]').click(function(e) {

    /* Prevent default actions */
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    /* Get the id (the number appended to the end of the classes) */
    var name = $(this).attr('class');
    var id = name[name.length - 1];

    /* Show the correct popup box, show the blackout and disable scrolling */
    $('#popup-box-'+id).show();
    $('#blackout').show();
    $("html,body").css("overflow","hidden");

});
```

I need both preventDefault and stopPropagation to stop some other stuff happening. Can you see any errors or a way to stop this auto scrolling to the top? Thanks!

Quick Edit:

I'm also running a function which centers the box using

```
$(window).scroll(centerBox);
```

I'm unsure if this would affect scrolling in some odd way in firefox. The contents of this function are just adding CSS, so I doubt they would have any effect on it.

**Another Edit:**

A link to try it out. Not working in Firefox for me. 
http://inserthtml.com/demo/internal-popup/

Comment: Have you tried moving the popup out of the screen instead of hiding it, then placing it back to show it?? That will guarantee its state is preserved.

Comment: I've set it to position: absolute. This is the easiest way to do it IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, i see nothing wrong in the script. it should be preventing the "top jump" even only with `e.preventDefault()`. try stripping it down to this. it should tell if this handler is causing it or not

```
$('[class*=popup-link]').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();   //prevent the click from jumping esp on hashes
    e.stopPropagation();  //prevent from any parent click handlers that didn't prevent the jump

    //no code here for now

    return false;         //the natural way to prevent the jump
});
```

if this code prevents the jump, then there is something in the rest of your code that causes it especially broken scripts. check the console for errors also

Comment: I tried it, it didn't work. Check out the link for a demo. You might have to resize the window, scroll down and click the link to see it go back up to the top.

Comment: it's your scroller script that elevates the page. it's not the jump caused by a hash change (i tested changing the href to a "dead hash" `#` and it didn't change the hash, so `e.preventDefault()` did work as expected). try to check the coordinates of your scroll. it may be way off.

Comment: For anyone wondering, I just added $('html').scrollPos($(window).scrollTop); to all the click events.

Answer (score 1):

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

is equivalent to

```
return false;
```

Change them, and you will be fine

Comment: I tried it, it didn't work. Check out the link for a demo. You might have to resize the window, scroll down and click the link to see it go back up to the top.

Comment: @Johnny, What exactly is that you want? Explain in plain words please :)